# Event is not firing in jQuery

Tags: jquery, cakephp

I have add form where i want to select the person and selected person will display in DIV (addcontact). When i will click on select contact one pop-up will open and then i will select contact from popup.

When i use my jQuery code in console then its works for me but in same time it is not working.

```
    <div id = "addcontact"></div>
      <?php echo $this->Html->link(__('Select Contact'),
         array('controller' => 'opportunities', 
             'action' => 'contact_search1', 'full_base' => true),
                 array('id'=>'contact-popup', 'class' => 'green-btn')) ?>
```

When user will click on below link then the text should display in above div. for that i have written jQuery. i have referred so many links but not worked for me.

```
<?php echo $this->Html->link($contactsearchs['Lead']['first_name'].' 
 '.$contactsearchs['Lead']['last_name'] , 'javascript:void(0);', 
  array('id' => 'connam', 'class' => 'test', 
        'lid1' => $contactsearchs['Lead']['id'])); ?>
```

Here is the jQuery

```
$(document).on('click', '.test a', function(e){
    var conName1 = jQuery(this).html();
    var lid1 = jQuery(this).attr('lid1');
    jQuery('#addcontact').html(conName1);
    jQuery('#OpportunityConLeadID').val(lid1);
    $.colorbox.close();
     e.preventDefault();
    alert(conName1+"=="+lid1);
});
```

Can anyone help me out with this query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shouldn't your selector be `$(document).on('click', 'a.test', function(e){` ? (as in `a.test` rather than `.test a`?

Do you get the alert when you click your link?

Comment: No, I dont even get alert. i used this code in the console.it is working fine. but when i used the same code in file then it is not even fire the event. and i have tried the selector as $('.test').on('click'..... This is also not working.

Comment: First step is just to get an alert showing. `$('.test').click(function(){ alert('hi')});` should do it.

Comment: Yes, I have been trying for the same but thats also not working.

Answer (score 0):

It must be either `.test` as selector or `a.test`, see [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/d098p4vs/1/)

Reason: a selector `.test a` means: Element of class "test" with a **subelement** `a`

`a class"test"...` is an element of type `a` and class `test` and thus not matching `.test a`.

Inverse test: `<p class="test"><a ...` is firing the event, as can be seen in the fiddle.